# HTML to PDF Conversion in android app

Tags: android, jspdf

Is it possible to convert html to pdf using **jsPdf** in android app ( without using cordova or phone gap) and save the file in device local.?

I tried this and onclick of button i am calling jspdf convertion logic, but pdf is not generating.

In adb log I see below waring on click of button.

*Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 1153*

I am using jspdf library, Filesaver.js.

Comment: https://github.com/jebalialaeddine/Android-ConvertToPDF

Comment: have you found a solution? care to share?

Comment: No, I am still trying to find solution. If I try to load the HTML file in android chrome browser  jsPDF is converting and saving pdf file. But it is failing in app ( chromium webview is being used)

Answer (score 9):

This [class](https://github.com/blink22/react-native-html-to-pdf/blob/master/android/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java) might help you.
But to compile, it must be in package ".../java/android/print/"

Here is a simple code example :

```
PdfConverter converter = PdfConverter.getInstance();
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "file.pdf");
String htmlString = "<html><body><p>WHITE (default)</p></body></html>";
converter.convert(getContext(), htmlString, file);
// By now the pdf has been printed in the file.
```

Comment: You completely replaced the Android "copy left" AGPL dependency? That is genius! Thank you!

Comment: @EdoftheMountain Thank you!

Comment: 'LayoutResultCallback()' is not public in 'android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Comment: Have you placed the class, shared in the answer, in a package with a hierarchy like ".../java/android/print/" ?

Comment: @IslamSalah How can we place the class in in a package with a hierarchy like the above?

Comment: Creating android.print and putting it inside did not work for me

Comment: Have you tried sth like?
`my-project-dir/app/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java`

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing for devices with API level 19+, then you can avoid 3rd party library. Please check the following link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument.html

If you are developing for API level below 19, then check the following links:

http://manzzup.blogspot.in/2014/05/creating-pdf-file-from-dynamic-html-in.html

If you strictly want to use jsPdf, then try to use jspdf.debug.js.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Currently I am using androids Print framework. We want pdf to be generated and saved without any popup. That is not supported in android print framework.

Comment: I have included jspdf library, jspdf.debug.js. I have a button on HTML page  to call pdf conversion, which calls jspdf function. But onclik of button not generating pdf . If I open the HTML file on browser in android device, it tries to generate and download the pdf file ( download blocked saying can download only from HTTP or HTTPS URLs- this is other issue)

Comment: For examples see https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs