# Android Studio : Adding a new java file to an existing package - "Unresolved Reference"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-package

I was looking the [HTML to PDF Conversion in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055979/html-to-pdf-conversion-in-android-app)

I have a problem to do the "it must be in package ".../java/android/print/" from solution number 1. 
How can I add the PdfConverter.java in android.print packages and the android studio recognise it ?

When I add it manually, fixing an PdfConverter.java and add it to the directory, the android studio do not recognise it and i got "Unresolved Reference : PdfConverter".

Is there another way, appropriate, to add the PdfConverter.java in the android.print package without getting the above error ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please share the code for convenience. thanks

Comment: @HaseebMirza I updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PdfConverter class is accessing PrintDocumentAdapter, from Android SDK's android.print package. You should made a package in project named android.print and I put PdfConverter class there and there would be no errors from lint in IDE.

Structure should be same as on this github repo https://github.com/blink22/react-native-html-to-pdf/tree/master/android

Comment: Of course I tried the solution you provide... didn't work. It must be in the android.print.

Comment: If you do it then you take "Cannot access '<init>': it is package-private in 'WriteResultCallback'"

Comment: Yes I see, class is accessing PrintDocumentAdapter, from SDK's android.print package. Okay I have tried this, I've made a package in my project named android.print and I put this class there so there is no errors from lint in IDE. Same like on this github repo https://github.com/blink22/react-native-html-to-pdf/blob/master/android/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java

Answer (score 2):

Add the java class in such own-made package tree (right-click on java directory -> New -> Package -> name it "android", then do the same with "print", then add to this package the PdfConverter):

[image]